# Excel Function not updating/working until its re-entered?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

So I have this excel document, works as intended and the functions are all working and valid. However, I am having an error sometimes without changing the formula. It appears to not work or update until I have manually pressed enter again on the cell, which then works perfectly.
This is the formula that's been giving me problems.

`=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSITTUTE('SheetName'!CellNumber," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")),"")`
`=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSITTUTE('SheetName'!CellNumber," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[2]")),"")`
`=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSITTUTE('SheetName'!CellNumber," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[3]")),"2nd Cell")`

The function is supposed to bring data from another sheet and have it divided into three parts, separated by empty space. If the last cell is empty, as in there are only two parts to the data, it copies the 2nd part.
The formula itself works fine and all, but sometimes when I send the file to someone or I happen to open it, it returns blank until I click on the cell and type enter.

Any fixes to this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'll just be adding a comment to press F9 in the meanwhile.

Comment: Check your excel calculation option either it set to automatic or manual.

Comment: I checked it and it was already set to automatic. It's weird how sometimes it works flawlessly and other times it just comes out of nowhere when it hasn't been touched.

Comment: It seems to happen when it's uploaded to a server and opened with Excel Online. I just used a different formula to separate them and so I don't think the problem will persist.

Comment: Excel online doesn't support `FILTERXML()`

Comment: `FILTERXML()` is available from Excel 2013, and doesnt supports Excel web as well

Answer (score 1):

"Force Excel to manual recalculate all of the formulas in the workbook even if they have not changed since the last calculation by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F9 on Windows and (I assume on Mac) Cmd+Alt+F9. If that doesn't work you can also try adding Shift which additionally rechecks dependent formulas before recalculating."

copied from this answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/1261444/custom-formula-not-updating